# JMX client that can persist gathered information

Tags: java, performance, jmx

We've added performance measures to our application and are exposing them using
JMX. Now we would like to gather and store performance data for analysis, in files or in a database.

Does anyone know of a JMX client, open source or commercial, that can persist gathered information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JRockit Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jrockit/missioncontrol/index.html) can persist JMX data to log-rotated XML-files that you can open up and view in the gui.

Answer (score 0):

you can attach logging functionality to jconsole itself and log mbean output etc.